# Use file command to get the correct type for an incomplete file

Tags: linux, file

Suppose I just don't have the whole file, I just download the first part and it contains all the file signature/magic bytes. Can I use file command in Linux to get its type? I think this command detect the file signature at the beginning, but I am not sure if they have more validation of the rest of the files.

Comment: You can determine which parts of a file are checked by file(1) by inspecting this https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir  collection of file type signatures, which is used by file(1), and by reading output from `man 5 magic'.  Usually indeed some limited part of the start of a file contains the determinant file type. The aforementioned list may inform you as to what 'limited' in this context means.

Answer (score 2):

`file(1)` will look by default at the first 1Mb of the file.

If you're using it as a library (`libmagic`) from your own program, you can change that with `magic_setparam(MAGIC_PARAM_BYTES_MAX)`, see its [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libmagic.3.html).